# Has anyone gotten GiveWP to work with CiviCRM

Tags: civicontribute, plugin

One of my associates wants to use GiveWP for donation forms. GiveWP has a plugin

https://shop.civivip.com/civi-plugins/give-donation-pages-integration/

The current version is called
civivip_give-0.3.0-beta

Does beta mean it is not released for production sites?

Comment: We used to use GiveWP - now we use CiviCRM exclusively. What features do you have with GiveWP that you aren't getting with CiviCRM and Wordpress?

Comment: We couldn't get the donation form using CiviCRM to look as nice as the form he can make with GiveWP. That is the only reason he wants to use GiveWP.

Comment: Ben - use Caldera Forms integration - you can make it look even better.

Comment: @themak Maybe but you are limited in payment gateways you can use.

Comment: Is there a payment processor that givewp supports that civicrm caldera doesn't?

Comment: @themak, Yes, I use USAEpay and they do not have integration with CF as far as I can tell

Answer (score 1):

CiviVIP doesn't make their plugins freely available, so it's very difficult to find support from folks outside of CiviVIP.  I would ask CiviVIP support, they should be able to answer this.